# Way to find a number at the end of a string in Smalltalk

Tags: string, integer, smalltalk

I have different commands my program is reading in (i.e., print, count, min, max, etc.). These words can also include a number at the end of them (i.e., print3, count1, min2, max6, etc.). I'm trying to figure out a way to extract the command and the number so that I can use both in my code.

I'm struggling to figure out a way to find the last element in the string in order to extract it, in Smalltalk.

Comment: Hint: Notice that `String` is a subclass of `SequenceableCollection`. Have you browsed it?

Comment: As Leandro gave you very helpful hint, tell us what did you try and where you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't told which incarnation of Smalltalk you use, so I will explain what I would do in [Pharo](https://pharo.org/), that is the one I'm familiar with.

As someone that is playing with Pharo a few months at most, I can tell you the sheer amount of classes and methods available can feel overpowering at first, but the environment actually makes easy to find things. For example, when you know the exact input and output you want, but doesn't know if a method already exists somewhere, or its name, the Finder actually allow you to search by giving a example. You can open it in the world menu, as shown bellow:

[image: Finder location]

By default it seeks selectors (method names) matching your input terms:

[image]

But this default is not what we need right now, so you must change the option in the upper right box to "Examples", and type in the search field a example of the input, followed by the output you want, both separated by a ".". The input example I used was the string 'max6', followed by the desired result, the number 6. Pharo then gives me a list of methods that match that:

[image]

To get what would return us the text part, you can make a new search, changing the example output from number 6 to the string 'max':

[image]

Fortunately there is several built-in methods matching the description of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are more elegant ways, I suppose, but you can make use of the fact that `String>>#asNumber` only parses the part it can recognize. So you can do

```
'print31' reversed asNumber asString reversed asNumber
```

to give you 31. That only works if there actually is a number at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where we can presume the input data has a specific form, ie, the only numbers appear at the end of the string, and you want all those numbers. In that case it's not too hard to do, really, just:

```
    numText := 'Kalahari78' select: [ :each | each isDigit ].
    num := numText asInteger. "78"
```

To get the rest of the string without the digits, you can just use this:

```
    'Kalahari78' withoutTrailingDigits. "Kalahari"6
```

As some of the Pharo "OGs" pointed out, you can take a look at the String class (just type CMD-Return, type in String, hit Return) and you will find an amazing number of methods for all kinds of things. Usually you can get some ideas from those. But then there are times when you really just need an answer!